# Multiple queries in E v5.6 REST high level client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

How can I have multiple query in Search API in elasticsearch v5.6 in rest high level client? I need to have OR and AND queries in the search query.
I've been using searchSourceBuilder, it only has one matchQuery.

```
QueryBuilder matchQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.matchQuery(field, query);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

BoolQueryBuilder finalQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();

For OR clauses you can use:

finalQuery.should().add(`your query`);

For AND clauses you can use:

finalQuery.must().add(`your query`);

You can link them however you want, and you can nest them as the logic dictates.

Comment: Hey, could you show an example for nesting boolQueryBuilder? It'd be of much help!

Comment: Sure.
BoolQueryBuilder finalQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
BoolQueryBuilder intermediateQuery= QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
QueryStringQueryBuilder queryCats = queryStringQuery("cat");
QueryBuilder existsQuery = existsQuery("name");

intermediateQuery.must().add(queryCats);
intermediateQuery.must().add(existsQuery);

finalQuery.should().add(intermediateQuery);
finalQuery.should().add(queryStringQuery("dog");

This code should find all the cats which have a name and all the dogs.

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks man, this is exactly what I'm looking for!